# Understanding Timeout In Partitioned Batch Jobs

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am trying to understand the ways timeouts cal be specified for partitioned steps.

- jmsoutbound-gateway  receive-timeout
- jmsoutbound-gateway  reply-timeout
- jmsoutbound-gateway  repyListener receive-timeout
- partition handler messagingOperations receive-timeout

I want to be able to timeout when a step takes too long and clean up. By looking at the stack trace, the reply listener does not go away after partition ends (and may receive a late responding message after job has completed).

Answer (score 0):

1. The time the executor thread will wait in the gateway for a reply to arrive (partition to complete) before giving up.
2. A timeout when writing to the reply-channel - in general will only apply if the send can block - such as when the reply channel is a bounded queue channel that is full.
3. When using a reply listener, the container polls the JMS client for messages, this timeout is simply how long the thread blocks in the client waiting for a reply before looping around and waiting again - it has no bearing on messages timing out; it only really affects how quickly the container will respond to a `stop()`.
4. The time the partition handler will wait for all partitions to complete (unless `pollRepositoryForResults` is true in which case, the handler's `timeout` property represents that and the receive timeout is not used).

So it sounds like #4 is what you want.